# Update Shopify cart product list using AJAX

Tags: jquery, ajax, shopify

I have 'Ajaxified' my cart on Shopify, when I click the 'Add to cart' button on a product page, the price updates in the top right hand corner of the screen and the product is added to the cart without a page refresh.

When you click the price in the top right hand corner, it reveals a dropdown showing you what products are in your basket (It shows product - image, url, price & quantity).

However, when you click 'Add to cart' this list of products does not update until you refresh the page.

How do I get this list to refresh (or how do I add the product to the list in the AJAX request)??

I have tried adding this into the ajaxify cart module (https://raw.githubusercontent.com/carolineschnapp/ajaxify-cart/master/ajaxify-cart.liquid):

```
$.getJSON(_config.shopifyAjaxCartURL, function(cart) {
    $("#dropdown-cart").append('<tr><td><a href="'+PRODUCT.URL+'" class="dropdown-product-image"><img src="'+PRODUCT.IMAGE+'"  alt="'+PRODUCT.DESCRIPTION+'" /></a></td><td class="restrain-width"><a href="'+PRODUCT.URL+'" class="small">PRODUCT.NAME</a></td><td class="text-right"><span class="small">PRODUCT.QUANTITY</span></td></tr>');
});
```

This updates the cart with the table rows and cells, but I do not know how to call the correct variables for `PRODUCT.****`. I have tried liquid (`{{ product.title }}`) variables but these do not work for me.

I also tried to use `cart.item`, `cart.product` `cart.product_title`, as `cart.` is referenced in the code already, but this just broke the script.

Does anyone know **how to simply refresh this form without a page refresh after the button is clicked** (this would be perfect!), or **how to add products using the route i've started down above?**

Comment: You're asking for someone to do your work for you. They wont. You also need to understand jquery (at least a little) in order to do this. Anyway cart.js returns a json object that you can iterate over and to access all the products loop through (you can use jquery's each() method for that). http://docs.shopify.com/support/your-website/themes/can-i-use-ajax-api#get-cart You can also refer to this since your question is a more or less a duplcate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26379057/show-product-quantity-in-cart-in-products-div-with-ajax/26390034#26390034

Comment: Thanks for the help @FunkDoc - I'm absolutely not asking for someone to 'do the work for me' however, I just wanted some light shining on why I can't call the variables. As far as I can see, i'm calling cart.js, then trying to call something like `cart.title` (in the question you linked to they call `cart.item_count` for example) but then it errors, I just wanted to know if i'm using the wrong naming convention or something, or if i'm completely off the mark.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So i've finally figured out where I was going wrong, I was trying to call `cart.title` where it should have been `cartItem.title`. Then I just looped these in jQuery with `each`.

Here's my full code:

```
$.each(cart.items, function(index, cartItem) {
   $("#dropdown-cart").append('<tr><td><a href="'+cartItem.url+'" class="dropdown-product-image"><img src="'+cartItem.image+'" alt="product image"/></a></td><td class="restrain-width"><a href="'+cartItem.url+'" class="small">'+cartItem.quantity+' '+cartItem.title+'</a></td><td class="text-right"><span class="small">'+(Shopify.formatMoney(cartItem.line_price, "{{ shop.money_format | remove: "'" | remove: '"' }}"))+'</span></td></tr>');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

shopify have its own ajax methods, that you can use to you ajax cart

[shopify cart.js](http://docs.shopify.com/support/your-website/themes/can-i-use-ajax-api)

Comment: I've been looking at that documentation, when I try and call `title ` for example, it breaks the AJAX and just sends me to the cart when I click 'add to cart'. I'm not too hot with AJAX stuff, any idea how to even start making it work?

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me perfectly! Outdated post maybe, but for those looking where to input this code it's under:

```
$.getJSON(_config.shopifyAjaxCartURL, function(cart)
```